# Program crashes with a short dump on logon

Tags: abap

As I logon into SAP Easy Access I see a short dump.

I have attached the short dump screenshot.

Looks like the function group I created in one of my programs, has an issue possibly with the includes.

I logged out after facing the error, upon logging in each time I get a short dump

I believe SAP program SAPLSHI20 is trying to read the function group includes. The program SAPLSHI20 has been created and maintained by SAP

I am creating test objects in a sandbox, and the objects are saved locally.

Using TCodes like /nSE80, /nSE37, /nSE38 also take me to a short dump.

I don't want to recreate my client as I will loose lots of programs and created tables and table entries.

Question) As I get a short dump right after logging in how can i access the object navigator and remove the function group created.

[image]

Comment: Check SAP Note 1322914. Looks like it addresses your issue.
https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1322914

Comment: This is one of those cases where I would call the basis administrators and ask them to restore the system from backup.

Comment: In case of a system restore I will loose all my work- my programs, tables and table entries. Should I raise a ticket with SAP Product Support?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the function group you created. I think somebody imported an SAP Note without its dependencies.

Comment: Does transaction SNOTE dump as well? If not, go there and check if somebody implemented the note mentioned by @ThomasErdösi.

Comment: The system was eventually rebuilt by basis team through transport request.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to check a DUMP in SAP ABAP is using ST22 TCODE, this transaction will provide useful information about error because causes could be severals:

1. Bad syntax programming, but if this is a SAP standard program is less possible.
2. The program SAPLSHI20 must be patched using a SAP NOTE.
3. There are several notes for fix issues due to unicode mismatch.
4. Plese talk with your basis support.

Check these notes: 1882544 1897077 655331 may be can help you.